# Extract AddressEntry object details for Exchange User

Tags: vba, outlook

Is there a way to extract the details in this dialog box via VBA?

[Details Dialog Box http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC84336.gif](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC84336.gif)

I need, especially the content in the E-Mail address tab.

Comment: Very late to the party, but perhaps if you have not found a solution, you can work with the `AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser` object, which should contain most of that information.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23668368/1467082) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can pretty much get the fields easily, the E-mail Addresses is the harder part. References: [Microsoft Exchange Property Tags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526844%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx)

This code exports some details but most importantly the Email addresses to a text file.

```
Sub ListGAL()
    On Error Resume Next
    Const LogFile = "C:\Test\OLK_GAL.log"
    Const sSCHEMA = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x"
    Const PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES = &H800F101E

    Dim oNameSpace As NameSpace, oGAL As AddressList, oEntry As AddressEntry
    Dim oFSO As Variant, oLF As Variant, oExUser As ExchangeUser, i As Long

    ' Oulook objects
    Set oNameSpace = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    ' Global Address List object
    Set oGAL = oNameSpace.AddressLists("Global Address List")
    '----------
    ' Log file objects
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oLF = oFSO.CreateTextFile(LogFile)
    '----------
    For Each oEntry In oGAL.AddressEntries
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print i & vbTab & oEntry.Name
        If oEntry.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeUserAddressEntry Then
            oLF.WriteLine "Entry " & i & " (olExchangeUserAddressEntry)"
            oLF.WriteLine "Name: " & oEntry.Name
            oLF.WriteLine "Address: " & oEntry.Address
            Set oExUser = oEntry.GetExchangeUser
            ' SMTP ADDRESSES
            oLF.WriteLine "SMTP Addresses:"
            oLF.WriteLine vbTab & Join(oExUser.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(sSCHEMA & Hex(PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES)), vbCrLf & vbTab)
            Set oExUser = Nothing
            oLF.WriteLine String(50, Chr(151)) ' Separator
        End If
    Next
    '----------
    ' Close Log File, clean up
    oLF.Close
    Set oGAL = Nothing
    Set oNameSpace = Nothing
    Set oLF = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

i have go a function of reading the address-book:

```
Function Get_mail(Absender As String)
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutTI As Outlook.TaskItem
Dim OutRec As Outlook.Recipient

  Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application
  Set OutTI = OutApp.CreateItem(3)
  OutTI.Assign

  Set OutRec = OutTI.Recipients.Add(Absender)
  OutRec.Resolve

   If OutRec.Resolved Then
    On Error GoTo exit_function
        Get_mail = OutRec.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
   End If
exit_function: Exit Function
  Set OutApp = Nothing
  Set OutTI = Nothing
End Function
```

as far as I know you can only read out the Primary Mail-address from the mail-addresses-tab; to see what else there ist delete the part ".PrimarySmtpAddress", mahe the dot and you should get the list of other properties.

I am quite sure you need the reference on Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library.

The Input "Absender" can be any string . if this string can be resolved as address book-entry in an outlook-mail, you will also have a positive result from the code above.
To call the function, if for example you have a string "mail_adress_from_adressbook" you would put:

```
mail_adress_from_adressbook = get_mail("Joe Smith")
```

I hope this helps,
Max

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can access any GAL object property shown by Outlook (and then some) even if the properties are not explicitly exposed by the [AddressEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry) or [ExchangeUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser) objects using `AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` as long as you know the MAPI property's DASL name

The DASL property names can be retrieved using [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author): either click IAddrBook button to drill down to a particular address entry or, if you have a message addressed to one of the GAL recipients, click IMessage button, go to the GetRecipientTable tab, double click on the recipient to open it as IMailUser:

[image]

In your particular case, you need `PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES` (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x800F101F"`) - it is a multivalued string property, which means `AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` will return an array of strings. Each value is prefixed with the address type (e.g. `"EX:"` or `"smtp:"`), the default SMTP address will be prefixed with `"SMTP:"` (note the upper case):

```
Set User = Application.session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry
AddressList = User.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x800F101F")
If IsArray(AddressList) Then
  For i = LBound(AddressList) To UBound(AddressList)
    MsgBox AddressList(i)
  Next
End If
```